# How do I set up port forwarding for ssh traffic?

Tags: ssh, iptables, proxy, port-forwarding

I have two servers, a web server and an ssh server. Currently I have the web server behind a load balancer, while the ssh server has a subdomain pointed to it.

I'd like for it to be possible to ssh in directly to my naked domain instead of having to specify the subdomain. Right now users have to access ssh via x.domain.com instead of just domain.com.

I would like to route ssh and www traffic for my naked domain to different boxes on the back end. I've been playing around iptables, but can't seem to get this to work. My router box is virtual and only has one interface, eth0.

Comment: Please explain more about your network setup. You have a server that only does SSH? What's its purpose? What does your DNS look like?

Answer (score 1):

Nginx is a webserver, that can also function as a HTTP proxy. No, it doesn't route SSH traffic.

Load-balancing SSH traffic is not something you want to do. From your question I can't really figure out what you're trying to achieve, but it seems to me that you're looking in the wrong direction. Please explain more about your goal, and I'm sure we can help.